# Rails Group_By Antipattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, group-by

I frequently encounter a code smell when I use the Enumerable group_by method. Some old code I'm refactoring is a good example

```
def punctuality_report
  params[:date] ? @date = Date.strptime(params[:date], "%m/%d/%Y") : @date = Date.today
  params[:through] ? @through = Date.strptime(params[:through], "%m/%d/%Y") : @through = @date + 1
  time_range = @date.to_formatted_s(:db)..@through.to_formatted_s(:db)
  @orders = Order.daily.includes(:store).where('orders.created_at' => time_range).group_by{|o| o.store}
  @orders.each_key.each do |s|
    eval "@s#{s.id}_early = @orders[s].collect{|o| o if o.early?}.compact"
    eval "@s#{s.id}_avg_early = @s#{s.id}_early.count > 0 ? @s#{s.id}_early.collect{|o| o.earliness}.sum / @s#{s.id}_early.count : '0'"         
    eval "@s#{s.id}_late = @orders[s].collect{|o| o if o.late?}.compact"
    eval "@s#{s.id}_avg_late =  @s#{s.id}_late.count > 0 ? @s#{s.id}_late.collect{|o| o.lateness}.sum / @s#{s.id}_late.count : '0'"         
    eval "@s#{s.id}_on_time = @orders[s] - (@s#{s.id}_early | @s#{s.id}_late)"
  end
end
```

Okay so I'm coming through this and I see clearly we need to refactor this report out of an action on the orders controller and into a model of its own to clean up this implementation logic. There's one code smell out, but I still struggle with this orders.group_by hash.

The thing is when I am in the view layer I really want that hash. I need to get summaries from the orders but I need access to the stores. Using the group query method in Activerecord just returns me a relation, which is not as useful as the enumerable group_by hash. I feel like there's a better way to get what I need and reduce a lot of this querying and ruby processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really see anything wrong with the group_by method.  I really see an issue with the overuse of eval though [-; Eval is a much strong code smell (IMHO) than group_by

That being said, I did see some other areas for refactor:

```
# Consider this refactor:

def punctuality_report
  # I find this slightly more readable
  @date = (params[:date]) ? Date.parse(params[:date]) : Date.today
  @through = (params[:through]) ? Date.parse(params[:through]) : @date + 1.day

  # the .in_time_range(range) method can be defined as a scope on the Order model, and you can
  # get rid of that logic here
  # 
  @orders = Order.daily.includes(:store).in_time_range(@date, @through).group_by(&:store)

end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :in_time_range, lambda { |date, through| where('orders.created_at' => (date..through)) }

  # It looks like you already know how to collect the orders for your needs... ie Order#early, etc

end

# Now, consider in your views the ability to do this:
@orders.each do |store, orders|
  # the orders now are the orders that met the above qualifications for the store
  orders.early
  Order.average_of_orders(orders.early)
  orders.late
  Order.average_of_orders(orders.late)
  orders.on_time    
end
```

Comment: I like your definition of the scope, but i am afraid you missed the point of the `eval`.

Comment: You're right... I did.  Why are you dynamically setting instance variables? That means your view code has the same logic, in reverse, to figure out what instance variables were set. That's a big smell as well.  Why can't you define methods on order to retrieve subsets (such as all early orders), and display them with those methods?

Answer (score 1):

I think group_by is a perfectly valid tool when used appropriately. I had a method in a cron job that used a few nested group_by statements, and I was convinced this was causing significant slowdown. I spent 2 hours rewriting the method to get rid of group_by, and the run-time went from an hour and 8 minutes to an hour and 5 minutes. Hardly worth the effort.

On the other hand, that code has some serious issues. Those ternary operators actually made me laugh out loud, and the eval statements are just evil. Not only did they use eval, they used it badly. Invoking eval is very slow, and there's no reason that all 5 eval statements couldn't have been combined into one.

That said, even one eval statement in this method is too much. I'm sure there's a time and place for eval, but I've never needed it in my code. In my general experience, virtually all calls to eval could be replaced with send, which is much faster and safer.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt:

```
def punctuality_report
  @date    = params[:date]    ? Date.strptime(params[:date], "%m/%d/%Y")    : Date.today
  @through = params[:through] ? Date.strptime(params[:through], "%m/%d/%Y") : @date + 1

  time_range = @date.to_formatted_s(:db)..@through.to_formatted_s(:db)

  @orders = Order.daily.includes(:store).where('orders.created_at' => time_range).group_by{|o| o.store}

  @orders.each_key.each do |s|
    all_early = @orders[s].collect{|o| o if o.early?}.compact
    all_late  = @orders[s].collect{|o| o if o.late?}.compact
    self.instance_variable_set("@s#{s.id}_early", all_early)   
    self.instance_variable_set("@s#{s.id}_avg_early", all_early.count > 0 ? all_early.collect{|o| o.earliness}.sum / all_early.count : 0)         
    self.instance_variable_set("@s#{s.id}_late", all_late) 
    self.instance_variable_set("@s#{s.id}_avg_late", all_late.count > 0 ? all_late.collect{|o| o.lateness}.sum / all_late.count : 0)         
    self.instance_variable_set("@s#{s.id}_on_time", @orders[s] - (all_early | all_late) )
  end
end
```

In short: in the `eval` section only instance variables were added, and we can use `instance_variable_get` and `instance_variable_set` instead. Almost all occurences of `eval` can be avoided, but I also believe that `eval` sometimes can be extremely useful and very powerful.

The code more clearly expresses its intent: it will add a set of instance variables, which is immediately visible on sight.

I definitely do not consider the use of `group_by` to be a code smell.

Comment: Thanks, Nathanvda. I don't have the reputation to vote 'up' this answer yet but it's very helpful. I think Jaredonline's example addresses my group_by concerns in a style I prefer, but this code has shown me a much nicer way around my use of eval with some methods I didn't know about--much appreciated!